# Does it require to input covariance matrix for prcomp() in R?

Tags: r, pca

It seems prcomp() use SVD for calculating principal components. In this case, do we still need to supply covariance matrix to prcomp()?

Or can we say that:

- `prcomp, SVD based, input original matrix and center=TRUE`
- **is equivalent to**
- `princomp, for finding eign vectors based on covariance matrix`

Comment: I found a solution from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. So that for prcomp() function, it's just taking the original matrix and make sure center=TRUE is properly set.

p.s. I found the solution at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca 
However, it has not answered in stackoverflow so that I can't close my question.